# How to get changed object field from vuetify form written in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have the following vue component and the values are loaded correctly from the store and displayed on the form. However if I change the value in a field it is not updated in the store. How can I make it such that whenever I change a value in the form it is also committed to the store?

```
    <template>
      <v-form v-model="valid" justify="center"  class="mx-5"  :disabled="show">
        <v-row justify="center">
          <H1 class="my-10">{{coin}}</H1>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
          <H3 class="my-5 mx-10">Add account</H3>
        </v-row>
        <v-row justify="space-around">
          <v-text-field v-model="settings.key" :rules="[rules.required]" class="mx-12" label="API Key" />
        </v-row>
      </v-form>
    </template>

<script>
import store from '../store'
export default {
  name: "Settings",
  store,
  props: ["coin", "show"],
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    rules: {
      required: (value) => !!value || "Required.",
    },
  }),
  computed: {
    settings: { 
      get() { return store.getters.getSettingsBySymbol(this.coin) },
      set(value) { store.commit("setSettingsBySymbol", value) },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

==== EDIT =====

```
settings = {
  coin: "hh",
  key: "12345",
  secret: "ajksjlkuT6ty",
}
```

Comment: where is `botStore` coming from? in your set handler. Should it be `store` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo I'll change it in the question. Sorry

Comment: also for the `v-model`, it should be `settings` instead of `settings.key`

Comment: No settings is an object and key is a field in that object. The object has more fields that also need to be shown in the form, when I get this to work.